# Passing delegate to a constructor not working

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass a delegate as a parameter in the ctor of a class like this

```
class Foo
{
   protected delegate void CreateResource(object parameter);

   protected Foo(CreateResource res)
   {
   }

   public Foo(string resourceName)
     : this(CreateStreamRes)  // Compiler error
   {
   }

   protected void CreateStreamRes(object o)
   {
   }
}
```

But I get the following compiler error in the commented line: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CreateStreamRes(object)'".

However if I Add a variable inside the constructor like this

```
   public Foo(string resourceName)
     : this(CreateStreamRes)  // Compiler error
   {
      CreateResource cr = CreateStreamRes; // OK
   }
```

it compiles that line successfully.

It seems like the C# treats the constructor as a static method. Because if I add the **static** keyword to the CreateStreamRes(object o) method it compiles nice.

Can someone explain me why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a non-static method there, because the object hasn't been constructed yet! Just define `CreateStreamRes` as static and be done with it!

Now, I'm sure Eric Lippert can give you a proper explanation about why this is the case, but I think of it like this: Using the `:this()` syntax will get translated into calling that constructor *first* and then doing whatever is in the constructor body afterwards. So you can't really use instance methods on an object that doesn't exist yet, right?

You could factor out the portion body of the constructor and call that:

```
class Foo
{
   protected delegate void CreateResource(object parameter);

   protected Foo(CreateResource res)
   {
       Initialize(res);
   }

   protected void Initialize(CreateResource res)
   {
   }

   public Foo(string resourceName)        
   {
       Initialize(CreateStreamRes(res));
   }

   protected void CreateStreamRes(object o)
   {
   }
}
```

This works, because by the time you call `Initialize`, the object has been allocated. *Inside* the constructor you are free to use instance methods.

Comment: Thank you guys. You're right the object is not created yet. I think this is the only case where we can call a method before the object is constructed that's why I get stunned when I saw the error. Thank you @Daren I've refactored as you suggested and it works now.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call instance method when calling the `:this()` keyword. That's because the instance of the class is not yet created. If you need to invoke some method there it must be static.